# Gnu parallel and ack not playing nicely due to stdin, pipe

Tags: bash, ack, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use `parallel` and `ack` together to do some searching in parallel. However, `ack` seems to insist on using `stdin` if it finds itself in a pipe, even if you give it files to search:

```
$ echo hello > test.txt

$ ack hello test.txt
hello

$ echo test.txt | xargs ack hello
hello

$ echo test.txt | parallel ack hello {}

# ack thinks it should be searching stdin:
$ echo test.txt | parallel ack -f {}
-

# even though parallel is indeed passing test.txt:
$ echo test.txt | parallel --dry-run ack hello {}
ack hello test.txt
```

What do I need to do to get `ack` and `parallel` to play nicely?

Comment: Consider running `parallel --bibtex` once to avoid the `--no-notice`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens on the current dev branch as well (`9cc2407`).  The reason for this is that when standard input is a pipe, ack tries to be helpful and assumes you're trying to search that input stream.  We've not seen this behavior before, so I've brought it up on the ack developers mailing list.  In the meantime, you can use `--nofilter` to override ack's default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to this line in `ack`:

```
$is_filter_mode = -p STDIN;
```

So these two situations are treated differently in `ack`:

```
cat file | ack ...
ack < file ...
```

The workaround for you seem to be to add a `cat`:

```
echo test.txt | parallel cat {} \| ack hello
```

This works in `ack` 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

I think ack is sick: Its behaviour is not deterministic, but it produces different output from time to time. Here I run the same command 100 times. 54 of them give "hello: No such file or directory". Note `ack` is being run by `bash` not by GNU Parallel.

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -N0 echo ack hello test.txt > test.sh
$ bash test.sh 2>&1 | sort | uniq -c
 54 hello: No such file or directory
100 hi
```

I can reproduce this behaviour when running this by hand 100 times:

```
$ ack hello test.txt
<<Sometimes:>> hello: No such file or directory
hi
```

Comment: hmm, I'm unable to reproduce these results. It's consistent for me.

Comment: I just tested on Linux Mint 15 and Debian 7.0: I still get the inconsistent results. What O/S are you running?

Comment: Huh. Arch Linux. `ack 2.12`, `perl 5.18.2`.

Comment: I can reproduce your findings with `ack 2.12`.